# Can’t choose handshake emoji color

Tags: ios, keyboard

It only lets me choose yellow:

[image]

For all the others, it’s no issue selecting color:

[image]

Comment: I think this particular emoji just doesn't have alternate colors? Not sure there's much you can do about that. It may not even be in the unicode spec.

Comment: ...Well, it *is* in the unicode spec, but apparently isn't supported on Apple platforms as of now, seeing as how the non-image versions all appear yellow on my Mac. https://emojipedia.org/handshake-type-6/